# convert with rails time helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

Rails offers helpers like `24.hours`, `1.minute` etc. How can I get the number of `minutes` in `1.hour`?

Comment: 60 minutes are in an hour. Helper-free! No, but seriously, what are you asking for?

Comment: Also, what are you looking to do with this? Some context might help

Comment: See my comment to Dylan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option, if you want to stick with the `1.hour` style language, is to divide by a single "minute":

```
1.hour / 1.minute
# => 60

5.hours / 1.minute
# => 300
```

Comment: I was looking for some helper to do these kind of conversions, and this will do. This is not perfect, because you have to be aware of the  original unit. It'd be best to have an API where I take a var `time_interval` and can convert it to any unit. Still funny that the intuitive approach `1.hour.minutes` produces the wrong result.

Comment: Yeah, can't chain them (you'd think you could), it just evaluates as `(1.hour).minutes`, or `3600.minutes`.

Answer (score 0):

`n.minutes` or `n.hours` are numerically kept in the form of `seconds` so to convert in minutes try this

```
hour_in_minutes = 1.hour/60
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
1.hours/1.minute
```

At the end, `1.hours`, etc. is just a `Fixnum`

Answer (score -2):

`1.hour.minutes` will return 60 minutes.

Comment: Is it just me or it's not working? In rails (3.2) console:  irb(main):013:0> 1.hour  
=> 3600 seconds  
irb(main):014:0> 1.hour.minutes  
=> 216000 seconds